# How 'First_open' is related to 'update_with_analytics' in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics, facebook-analytics

I'm finding it hard to make distinction between parameters related to `first_open` event. Those parameters are `system_app`, `system_app_update` and `update_with_analytics`.

Can someone clearly define them and give concrete examples when these parameters will change their values.

I'm following this [link](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7061705?hl=en&ref_topic=7029512), but I couldn't get hold of these concepts.

I have understood `previous_first_open_count` though. If it's 0 then it's new install and if > 0 then re-install. Is it possible that `previous_first_open_count` = 0 AND  `update_with_analytics` = 1.  If Yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

`update_with_analytics` = 1 means that the user has updated from a previous version that did not have analytics integrated. `previous_first_open_count` can be 0 since there will be no existing first_open events for the previous version of the app that didn't have any analytics collection.

`system_app` indicates whether or not the app is a system app. System apps are the apps that are preloaded on the device (not installed by user).

Comment: thanks for your wonderful answer. I have seen cases where **previous_first_open_count** > 0 AND **update_with_analytics** = 1. How this is possible? If old version was already linked with analytics then why **update_with_analytics = 1** was fired after upgrade? Or I'm missing something?

Comment: I have not researched this in depth but one possible scenario is that the user uninstalls the app/update and downgrades to a previous version of the app that does not have analytics and then gets a new version of the app at some point in the future.